# Enriching the Data in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, lookup

We will be ingesting data into an Index (Index1), however one of the fields in the document(field1) is an ENUM value, which needs to be converted into a value (string) using a lookup through a rest api call.
the rest api call gives a JSON in response like this which has string values for all the ENUMS.

```
{
values : {
"ENUMVALUE1" : "StringValue1",
"ENUMVALUE2" : "StringValue2"
}
}
```

I am thinking of making an index from this response document and use that for the lookup.
The incoming document has field1 as ENUMVALUE1 or ENUMVALUE2 (only one of them) and we want to eventually save StringValue1 or StringValue2 in the document under field1 and not ENUMVALUE1.

I went through the documentation of enrichment processor however I am not sure if that is the correct approach to handle this scenario.
While forming the match enrich policy I am not sure how match_field and enrich_fields should be configured.

Could you please advise if this can be done in Elastic and if yes what possible options do I have if the above one is not an optimal approach.

Comment: How many different enum values do you have? Is there a way to "export" all the data from the REST API? If yes, then it's easy to store that into an index and then build an enrichment index like you suggest.

Comment: @Val: There would be 5-10 of them, coming through different json responses when the rest api call is made. Let's say even if I collate them into a single index, I am not able to understand, how enrichment index will replace my enum value in the incoming request to stringvalue. The documentation that I read for enrichment is about adding additional fields based on an incoming input value. Could you please suggest how can the same matching index value be used. Using this as reference:  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/match-enrich-policy-type.html

Comment: If you have only 5 to 10 items, you don't need an enrich index, a simple ingest  pipeline would be more than sufficient

Comment: ingest pipeline with enrich processor? my question is still the same, how do I form the enrich policy for that.

Comment: nope, for 5-10 items you don't need an enrich processor, a simple ingest pipeline that sets the string value according to the enum value would be perfectly efficient

Comment: ok, sorry if this is a bit confusing, when I say 5-10 items, those are 5-10 responses from the rest API and each response is a big json payload with multiple ENUMS mapped to strings in it.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase again: how many different enum values do you have from all the different calls?

Comment: That must add up to somewhere 150-200 ENUMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, 150-200 enums might not be enough to use an enrich index, but here is a potential solution.

You first need to [build the source index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enrich-setup.html#create-enrich-source-index) containing all enum mappings, it would look like this:

```
POST enums/_doc/_bulk
{"index":{}}
{"enum_id": "ENUMVALUE1", "string_value": "StringValue1"}
{"index":{}}
{"enum_id": "ENUMVALUE2", "string_value": "StringValue2"}
```

Then you need to [create an enrich policy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enrich-setup.html#create-enrich-policy) out of this index:

```
PUT /_enrich/policy/enum-policy
{
  "match": {
    "indices": "enums",
    "match_field": "enum_id",
    "enrich_fields": [
      "string_value"
    ]
  }
}
POST /_enrich/policy/enum-policy/_execute
```

Once it's built (with 200 values it should take a few seconds), you can start building your ingest pipeline using an [`ingest` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enrich-setup.html#add-enrich-processor):

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/enum-pipeline
{
  "description": "Enum enriching pipeline",
  "processors": [
    {
      "enrich" : {
        "policy_name": "enum-policy",
        "field" : "field1",
        "target_field": "tmp"
      }
    },
    {
      "set": {
        "if": "ctx.tmp != null",
        "field": "field1",
        "value": "{{tmp.string_value}}"
      }
    },
    {
      "remove": {
        "if": "ctx.tmp != null",
        "field": "tmp"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Testing this pipeline, we get this:

```
POST _ingest/pipeline/enum-pipeline/_simulate
{
  "docs": [
    {
      "_source": {
        "field1": "ENUMVALUE1"
      }
    },
    {
      "_source": {
        "field1": "ENUMVALUE4"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Results =>

```
{
  "docs" : [
    {
      "doc" : {
        "_source" : {
          "field1" : "StringValue1"        <--- value has been replaced
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "doc" : {
        "_source" : {
          "field1" : "ENUMVALUE4"          <--- value has NOT been replaced
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

For the sake of completeness, I'm sharing the other solution without enrich index, so you can test both and use whichever makes most sense for you.

In this second option, we're simply going to use an ingest pipeline with a [`script` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/script-processor.html) whose parameters contain a map of your enums. `field1` will be replaced by whatever value is mapped to the enum value it contains, or will keep its value if there's no corresponding enum value.

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/enum-pipeline
{
  "description": "Enum enriching pipeline",
  "processors": [
    {
      "script": {
        "source": """
          ctx.field1 = params.getOrDefault(ctx.field1, ctx.field1);
        """,
        "params": {
          "ENUMVALUE1": "StringValue1",
          "ENUMVALUE2": "StringValue2",
          ... // add all your enums here
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Testing this pipeline, we get this

```
POST _ingest/pipeline/enum-pipeline/_simulate
{
  "docs": [
    {
      "_source": {
        "field1": "ENUMVALUE1"
      }
    },
    {
      "_source": {
        "field1": "ENUMVALUE4"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Results =>

```
{
  "docs" : [
    {
      "doc" : {
        "_source" : {
          "field1" : "StringValue1"        <--- value has been replaced
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "doc" : {
        "_source" : {
          "field1" : "ENUMVALUE4"          <--- value has NOT been replaced
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So both solutions would work for your case, you just need to pick up the one that is the best fit. Just know that in the first option, if your enums change, you'll need to rebuild your source index and enrich policy, while in the second case, you just need to modify the parameters map of your pipeline.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice. I used the first option of creating an enrich index and it solved my problem.

Comment: There is one problem that I am facing after implementing the pipeline. There are some array in the document object under which also I apply the enrichment. To access each element of the array I use foreach processor, however all the values of the ENUM are getting replaced with the same value. I tried to debug this, looks like in the foreach processor  I need multiple target_fields object and then need to compare them in the set processor. The if is not supporting this :  if ctx._ingest._value.enum==<mytargetfieldvalue>. Is there a way to do this comparison?

Comment: Please create a new thread (referencing this one for context) and explain your new issue there.