# Alternative to lookup datatype?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk, elasticsearch-painless

I wanted to populate a description field using its corresponding key, code, and another index having a key, lookup_code, column, and a corresponding description column but without the lookup datatype I am finding it hard to achieve a lookup on the index level since lookup data type, as well as scripted fields, have been deprecated. How can I achieve the same?

I tried using the following painless code since it is an alternative that was suggested in the documentation:

```
POST input_index/_search
{
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "input_desc": {
        "type": "lookup", 
        "target_index": "lookup_index", 
        "input_field": "input_code", 
        "target_field": "lookup_code", 
        "fetch_fields": ["lookup_desc"] 
    }
  },

  "_source": false
}
```

The lookup was successful but the input_desc was not populated in the index itself instead I got the lookup completed index as an output in console.

Comment: Where did you see that lookup runtime fields have been deprecated?

Comment: Personally, I would do it with an enrich index as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71932668/enriching-the-data-in-elastic-search/71963423#71963423